# Using JPA annotations with Hibernate to describe @OneToMany relationship where foreign key is only in child table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, h2

I have an existing data model that I'm very happy with:

```
public class Garden {
    private String name; // "Oak Grove"
    private List<Plant> plants;
}

public class Plant {
    private String name; // "Cherry Tomato"
}
```

I would like to map this in Hibernate with the following conditions:

1. The `Plant` class in Java does not maintain a reference to its parent `Garden`. This makes things more difficult in the Java tier, IMO.
2. The `PLANT` table should have a `GARDEN_ID` column which is a foreign key to the `GARDEN(ID)` column.

My initial setup, prior to the `@OneToMany` addition:

```
@Entity(name = "GARDEN")
public class Garden {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Oak Grove"

    // Not yet mapped
    private List<Plant> plants;
}

@Entity(name = "PLANT")   
public class Plant {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Cherry Tomato"
}
```

How can I define the `@OneToMany` annotation on the `List<Plant> plants;` in such a way that the foreign key reference is maintained in the `Plant`?

If I just add:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "GARDEN_ID")
private List<Plant> plants;
```

Then saving a garden with a plant fails like so:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "GARDEN_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into PLANT (NAME, ID) values (?, ?) [23502-191]
```

So it seems Hibernate isn't trying to persist the foreign key. Is there a way to accomplish this without completely mucking up my object model?

**Edit:** The way I'm testing this is with:

```
Garden garden = new Garden("Oak Grove");
garden.addPlant(new Plant("Cherry Tomato"));
gardenManager.save(garden);
```

In which the `save()` method looks very Hibernate-ey:

```
public void save(T item) {
    try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.saveOrUpdate(item);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred saving item: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing @JoinColumn and adding mappedBy to @OneToMany? @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        mappedBy = "garden")

Comment: @Nicholas Code added.

Comment: @RubioRic It's my understanding that `mappedBy` is used when there is a corresponding Java property (`private Garden garden`) on the child (`Plant`) class - this is not what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: @CraigOtis You're right. My mistake.

Comment: Can't reproduce (5.0.9.Final) I get two inserts and an update: Hibernate: insert into Member (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into Course (id) values (?)
Hibernate: update Course set member_id=? where id=?. See no difference other than class names.

Comment: Do you have your dialect set? "Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"

Comment: I'm using H2 with `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yogesh Sakurikar was close, but the bi-directional `@JoinColumn` was a bit off. Below you will see how to join bidirectionally or mono-riectionally

```
@Entity(name = "GARDEN")
public class Garden {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Oak Grove"

    // use this if you don't want a bi-directional relationship
    // @OneToMany
    // @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName="GARDEN_ID")
    // private List<Plant> plants;

    // use this if you want it bi-directional
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "garden")
    private Set<Plant> plants;
}

@Entity(name = "PLANT")   
public class Plant {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Cherry Tomato"

    // use this if you don't want a bi-directional relationship
    // @Column(name="GARDEN_ID")
    // private long gardenId;

    // use this if you want a bi-directional relationship
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GARDEN_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable = false)
    private Garden garden;

}
```

The code below assumes bi-directional relationship. Otherwise you'd need to know your `Garden.id` before you could fully describe any child `Plant`

```
Garden garden = new Garden("Oak Grove");
Plant plant = new Plant("Cherry Tomato")
plant.setGarden(garden); //don't forget to set the parent on the child
garden.addPlant(plant);
gardenManager.save(garden);
```

Comment: The issue is I'd rather the `Plant` _not_ know about the `Garden`. Otherwise, I need the "don't forget" bits of code that I find a bit cumbersome. I don't think the object model layer should make sacrifices to satisfy the database - rather, it should work _around_ the data.

Comment: Then you need a separate linking table.

Comment: Setting the parent to the child is the actually "cleaner" approach here because you don't need to know the ID of either. Your requirement would add a 3rd table (for which you should probably have a 3rd Entity) and which would be `@OneToOne` with `Plant` and `@ManyToOne` with `Gadren`... unless you want the same `Plant` in multiple `Garden`s, which would make them `@ManyToMany` and then DEFINITELY requires a join table.

Answer (score 1):

For one to many relationship, if the plant will going to hold the relationship, you need to define it using bi-direction.
Here is I think you should be able to achieve it:

```
@Entity(name = "GARDEN")
public class Garden {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Oak Grove"

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "garden")
    private List<Plant> plants;
}

@Entity(name = "PLANT")   
public class Plant {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name; // "Cherry Tomato"

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GARDEN_ID", nullable = false)
    Garden garden;
}
```

This bidirectional approach will let entity manager know that there exists a relationship between the two and since on one side it is one to many, for other side it become many to one. Hope this will help.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking for a way to map the current object model without needing to add a `Garden` to the `Plant`.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I would try this out too:@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="PLANT", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GARDEN_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
    , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="GARDEN_ID")})
    private Set<Plant> plants;